# How to allow IFrame to load pages only from specified domain?

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

For example, I'm developer of foo.com website. On one of my pages I've iframe with page from bar.com. I want to page in iframe to load another pages from bar.com (by clicking links), but restrict following links to another domains (clicking link in iframe that ponts to evil.com or whatever should display an error message).

Can I do this somehow? May be with help of javascript?

Comment: If you are the developer of the bar.com site as well, you can just add a click event to all <a> tags to enforce this (using jquery or something like that), but if you're not, I'm afraid you're out of luck, because the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) prevents the javascript of foo.bar from accessing the content of the iframe.

Comment: An alternative is to serve bar.com pages from a proxy on foo.com. If you for example do a google search, you will never get a link to a site, they all are https://www.google.com/url?=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bar.com%2Fpage.html

Comment: No, I can't change anything on bar.com.